# TexLive on Mac - commands return no results or errors

Tags: pdftex, texlive, mac, environment-variables, texlive-2016

You'll have to excuse me being new to TeX, but on my Mac, typing any TeX command (after installing TeXLive 2016 from the DVD) produces no result and doesn't even show an error, which makes me think that it must be environment variables. I just don't know how to edit those after installation nor do I even know what to change them to.

I type `pdflatex somefile.tex` and it does nothing.

I type `tex --version` and same thing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you on Sierra? Because then you might need to reinstall using the data from TUG.org/mactex, Sierra has an impact on how mactex works plus it came out after the DVD was released

Comment: I'm actually on Mavericks

Comment: Then that's a bit odd. What exactly did you install from the DVD?

Comment: I guess I should mention that installed the MacTeX basic package first. Then I got a hard copy of TeXLive 2016 and installed it from the disk, unchecking the "import previous package settings" option. Then I realized I'd forgotten to select the "complete" package option and reinstalled the DVD again. When I last did that, the directories it listed were as follows:

Comment: TEXDIR:
     /usr/local/texlive/2016
   TEXMFLOCAL (directory for site-wide local files):
     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
   TEXMFSYSVAR (directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var
   TEXMFSYSCONFIG (directory for local config):
     /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config
   TEXMFVAR (personal directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     ~/.texlive2016/texmf-var
   TEXMFCONFIG (personal directory for local config):
     ~/.texlive2016/texmf-config
   TEXMFHOME (directory for user-specific files):
    ~/texmf

Comment: I would suggest downloading/installing the full mactex unless you have serious space problems, it just saves you a lot of problems

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can purge all the texlive files off my machine, just in case?

Comment: Is there actually something called mactex basic? Seems more like texlive basic and that a path is needed to be added somewhere. No idea where as I'm not a Mac user

Comment: Look at the paths you listed, they have a common root, delete from there and down (as super user)

Comment: It was actually called BasicTeX on the webpage. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the full MacTeX from the DVD. It's a fairly simple two step process. Open the MacTeX folder and follow the instructions there. That should set up everything.

One more thing! If you are installing on a fresh install on Sierra, rather than an update from a previous OS version, download and install FixLinks.pkg from http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/. There is an explanation of the problem there.